# HTML no detecta link hacia otra página dentro de un div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, div, enlace

El problema es este, que cree un div para mostrar información y al añadirle después del texto un `<a><strong>TXT</strong></a>` no detecta como si fuera un hypervinculo

[image: COMO SE VE EN LA PAGINA]

Codigo:

```html
<div class="slide">

  <strong>IDEA</strong><br>

  <span class="descripcion">Descripcion muy breve de la idea</span><br>

  <span class="claves">-Palabras calves de la idea<br></span>

  <a href="#">
    <strong class="btn btn-light2">Colaborar</strong>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: pues al parecer esta bien compañero te envio printscreen, Saludos [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVQvN.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVQvN.jpg)

Comment: Ya encontre el error, lo que pasaba es que justo abajo habia una imagen de un logo de la pagina, pero la imagen tenia como espacio en blanco que no tenia ninguna ilustracion pero era parte de la imagen PNG, y el mouse no se ponia la flecha apuntando por que la imagen cubria el link y al darle click derecho me mostraba ocpciones pero de la imagen por que estaba encima del txt.

Comment: Aun asi gracias por su respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

En el artibuto `href=""` no estas dirigiendo a ninguna parte ni tiene un id o class para llamarlo con un evento Javascript / Jquery.

Lo primero hay que verificiar si el comportamiento del mouse aun es del tipo hipervinculo al ubicarte sobre este, el cual debe pasar de una flecha a una mano apuntando,

Lo otro es verificar las reglas css de que tiene en class "btn btn-light2", otra opcion es poner el hipervinculo dentro del

Prueba esta otra forma:

```
<strong class="btn btn-light2" ><a href="index.html">Colaborar</a></strong>
```

Comment: Ya encontre el error, lo que pasaba es que justo abajo habia una imagen de un logo de la pagina, pero la imagen tenia como espacio en blanco que no tenia ninguna ilustracion pero era parte de la imagen PNG, y el mouse no se ponia la flecha apuntando por que la imagen cubria el link y al darle click derecho me mostraba ocpciones pero de la imagen por que estaba encima del txt.

Comment: Aun asi gracias por su respuesta :)

Comment: @P0WDENDEVELOPER Si la respuesta fue la que solucionó tu caso o la más certera que pudo solucionar la pregunta, márcala como aceptada haciendo click en el check verde